# DML an associative array in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

can I operate an associative array as same as a normal table, to perform insert/delete/update action?

this code snippet could not compile and compiler shows emps is not a view or table but it seems to be defined as a TABLE object.

```
    DECLARE
    TYPE e_list IS TABLE OF employees_salary_history%rowtype INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    emps e_list;
    idx PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      UPDATE emps SET first_name= 'john'  WHERE email='jones@gmail.com'; 
    END;
    /
```

Comment: no, you can't do that